# Python - tkinter and glob.glob working togheter

Tags: python, tkinter

Im new to `tkinter` and trying to open the `explorer` (on windows) so that i can chose what folder i want to use in my program. I found a template for `tkinter` and altered it to work with my function and how i need the `filepath` to be. Before i tried using `tkinter` to "select my folder", i had manually writen the directory in the `glob.glob` function like this `glob.glob(r'C:\Users\Desktop\Spyder\*.log')` (and it worked). So my new ide was  to replace the pathname input from `r'C:\Users\Desktop\Spyder\*.log'` to a variabel that stored the same pathname but now it used tkinters `askdirectory()` to finde the directory inteed.

```
import glob
import os
from itertools import zip_longest
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import filedialog

#-------------Connect to Access2013------------------ 
class Application(tk.Frame):
    def __init__(self, master=None):
        super().__init__(master)
        self.pack()
        self.create_widgets()

    def create_widgets(self):

        self.select_folder = tk.Button(self)
        self.select_folder["text"] = "Open WindowsExplorer"
        self.select_folder["command"] = self.ask_directory_to_folder
        self.select_folder.pack(side="top")

        self.quit = tk.Button(self, text="QUIT", fg="red",
                              command=root.destroy)
        self.quit.pack(side="bottom")

    def ask_directory_to_folder(self):
        clerdatabase() # a funktion that resets the autonumber and deleats all data from every table
        print("Open!")
        filepath = filedialog.askdirectory()
        log_filepath = "r'"+ str(filepath +"/*.log'")
        right_log_filepath = log_filepath.replace('/','\ ').replace(' ','')
        find_filenames(right_log_filepath)

root = tk.Tk()
app = Application(master=root)
app.mainloop()

#--------------Scan selected folder for .log files and starts to scan files---------
def find_filenames(right_log_filepath): #finds every file in the chosen filepath

    print(right_log_filepath) # r'C:\Users\Desktop\Spyder\*.log'
    print("ok")
    filenames = [] # list for all the found filenames
    for filepath_search in glob.glob(str(right_log_filepath), recursive=True): #A for loop that opens every .log file in the chosen directory folder 
        print('run')
```

My problem ist that i don´t get the `for loop` `filepath_search` to work (it prints "ok"). But the word `run` inside the for loop dose not print, i guess it´s because it gets stuck somewhere before that? Someone who has more experience with tkinter that can help me? Thanks

Comment: It could be possible that `glob.glob` return 0 results and it simply doesn't iterate to execute `print('run')`. Try to add one more `print` statement after `for` loop.

Comment: Yes it prints after the for loop, so my problem is why glob.glob gets 0 when it should be the filepath as a str? @DenisFetinin

Comment: found sulotion, used eval()

Comment: How did you use eval? @sesar

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess issue caused by what is passed to `glob.glob` since it doesn't find anything. It seems that it is mostly related to the fact that you add `'` characters at the beggining and end of your right_log_filepath.

In `ask_directory_to_folder` function replace:

```
log_filepath = "r'"+ str(filepath +"/*.log'")
right_log_filepath = log_filepath.replace('/','\ ').replace(' ','')
find_filenames(right_log_filepath)
```

With:

```
from os import path  # should be at the top of your file
log_filepath = path.join(filepath, "*.log")
find_filenames(log_filepath)
```

Comment: yes, that should work, but i hade to use " \ " and join uses " / " (for some reason). But i found a solution where i made the string to a variabel with eval(). Thanks for taking the time!

Comment: `eval` should've helped because it removed extra single quotes from your path. Just write `log_filepath = str(filepath +"/*.log")` then and `eval` won't be needed. Still recommend to use path.join to join paths though. @sesar

Comment: Yeah your right, thanks! Made the changes now and works (Y)